# Create Stored Procedure in VS2012 to drop 4 tables at once?

Tags: sql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, stored-procedures, sql-scripts

In an MVC Web Application I'm working on, I have 4 specific tables that are used and automatically generated for Roles Authentication. After I created a migration and seed my database, I then run the application which creates these 4 tables.

Whenever I must modify my Model, I am forced to delete these 4 tables due to a reference constraint on my Users table. VS2012 does not allow me to selct all 4 tables and Delete at once, so I was wondering if there was a way for me to create a Stored Procedure I can excute to have the 4 Drop Scripts run at once?

Under `Server Explorer` I right-click `Stored Prcoedures` and then select `Add New Stored Procedure`. I am then presented the following template:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Procedure]
    @param1 int = 0,
    @param2 int
AS
    SELECT @param1, @param2
RETURN 0
```

Via the GUI I have copied the below auto-generated DROP Table commands when I click `DELETE` for each of the tables.

How do I go about created a Stored Procedure (or multiple?) in VS2012 to drop all 4 tables in one command?

```
/*
Deployment script for RandomDBdev

This code was generated by a tool.
Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
the code is regenerated.
*/

GO
SET ANSI_NULLS, ANSI_PADDING, ANSI_WARNINGS, ARITHABORT, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;

SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF;


GO
:setvar DatabaseName "RandomDBdev"
:setvar DefaultFilePrefix "RandomDBdev"
:setvar DefaultDataPath "C:\Users\arandomuser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\v11.0\"
:setvar DefaultLogPath "C:\Users\arandomuser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\v11.0\"

GO
:on error exit
GO
/*
Detect SQLCMD mode and disable script execution if SQLCMD mode is not supported.
To re-enable the script after enabling SQLCMD mode, execute the following:
SET NOEXEC OFF; 
*/
:setvar __IsSqlCmdEnabled "True"
GO
IF N'$(__IsSqlCmdEnabled)' NOT LIKE N'True'
    BEGIN
        PRINT N'SQLCMD mode must be enabled to successfully execute this script.';
        SET NOEXEC ON;
    END


GO
USE [$(DatabaseName)];


GO

IF (SELECT OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpErrors')) IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmpErrors
GO
CREATE TABLE #tmpErrors (Error int)
GO
SET XACT_ABORT ON
GO
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
GO
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
PRINT N'Dropping [dbo].[webpages_Membership]...';


GO
DROP TABLE [dbo].[webpages_Membership];


GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0
   AND @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;
    END

IF @@TRANCOUNT = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT  INTO #tmpErrors (Error)
        VALUES                 (1);
        BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    END


GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #tmpErrors) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
GO
IF @@TRANCOUNT>0 BEGIN
PRINT N'The transacted portion of the database update succeeded.'
COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
ELSE PRINT N'The transacted portion of the database update failed.'
GO
DROP TABLE #tmpErrors
GO
PRINT N'Update complete.';


GO
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*
Deployment script for RandomDBdev

This code was generated by a tool.
Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
the code is regenerated.
*/

GO
SET ANSI_NULLS, ANSI_PADDING, ANSI_WARNINGS, ARITHABORT, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;

SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF;


GO
:setvar DatabaseName "RandomDBdev"
:setvar DefaultFilePrefix "RandomDBdev"
:setvar DefaultDataPath "C:\Users\arandomuser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\v11.0\"
:setvar DefaultLogPath "C:\Users\arandomuser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\v11.0\"

GO
:on error exit
GO
/*
Detect SQLCMD mode and disable script execution if SQLCMD mode is not supported.
To re-enable the script after enabling SQLCMD mode, execute the following:
SET NOEXEC OFF; 
*/
:setvar __IsSqlCmdEnabled "True"
GO
IF N'$(__IsSqlCmdEnabled)' NOT LIKE N'True'
    BEGIN
        PRINT N'SQLCMD mode must be enabled to successfully execute this script.';
        SET NOEXEC ON;
    END


GO
USE [$(DatabaseName)];


GO

IF (SELECT OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpErrors')) IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmpErrors
GO
CREATE TABLE #tmpErrors (Error int)
GO
SET XACT_ABORT ON
GO
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
GO
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
PRINT N'Dropping [dbo].[webpages_OAuthMembership]...';


GO
DROP TABLE [dbo].[webpages_OAuthMembership];


GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0
   AND @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;
    END

IF @@TRANCOUNT = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT  INTO #tmpErrors (Error)
        VALUES                 (1);
        BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    END


GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #tmpErrors) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
GO
IF @@TRANCOUNT>0 BEGIN
PRINT N'The transacted portion of the database update succeeded.'
COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
ELSE PRINT N'The transacted portion of the database update failed.'
GO
DROP TABLE #tmpErrors
GO
PRINT N'Update complete.';


GO
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*
Deployment script for RandomDBdev

This code was generated by a tool.
Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
the code is regenerated.
*/

GO
SET ANSI_NULLS, ANSI_PADDING, ANSI_WARNINGS, ARITHABORT, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;

SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF;


GO
:setvar DatabaseName "RandomDBdev"
:setvar DefaultFilePrefix "RandomDBdev"
:setvar DefaultDataPath "C:\Users\arandomuser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\v11.0\"
:setvar DefaultLogPath "C:\Users\arandomuser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\v11.0\"

GO
:on error exit
GO
/*
Detect SQLCMD mode and disable script execution if SQLCMD mode is not supported.
To re-enable the script after enabling SQLCMD mode, execute the following:
SET NOEXEC OFF; 
*/
:setvar __IsSqlCmdEnabled "True"
GO
IF N'$(__IsSqlCmdEnabled)' NOT LIKE N'True'
    BEGIN
        PRINT N'SQLCMD mode must be enabled to successfully execute this script.';
        SET NOEXEC ON;
    END


GO
USE [$(DatabaseName)];


GO

IF (SELECT OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpErrors')) IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmpErrors
GO
CREATE TABLE #tmpErrors (Error int)
GO
SET XACT_ABORT ON
GO
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
GO
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
PRINT N'Dropping fk_RoleId...';


GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[webpages_UsersInRoles] DROP CONSTRAINT [fk_RoleId];


GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0
   AND @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;
    END

IF @@TRANCOUNT = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT  INTO #tmpErrors (Error)
        VALUES                 (1);
        BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    END


GO
PRINT N'Dropping [dbo].[webpages_Roles]...';


GO
DROP TABLE [dbo].[webpages_Roles];


GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0
   AND @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;
    END

IF @@TRANCOUNT = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT  INTO #tmpErrors (Error)
        VALUES                 (1);
        BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    END


GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #tmpErrors) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
GO
IF @@TRANCOUNT>0 BEGIN
PRINT N'The transacted portion of the database update succeeded.'
COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
ELSE PRINT N'The transacted portion of the database update failed.'
GO
DROP TABLE #tmpErrors
GO
PRINT N'Update complete.';


GO
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*
Deployment script for RandomDBdev

This code was generated by a tool.
Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
the code is regenerated.
*/

GO
SET ANSI_NULLS, ANSI_PADDING, ANSI_WARNINGS, ARITHABORT, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;

SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF;


GO
:setvar DatabaseName "RandomDBdev"
:setvar DefaultFilePrefix "RandomDBdev"
:setvar DefaultDataPath "C:\Users\arandomuser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\v11.0\"
:setvar DefaultLogPath "C:\Users\arandomuser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\v11.0\"

GO
:on error exit
GO
/*
Detect SQLCMD mode and disable script execution if SQLCMD mode is not supported.
To re-enable the script after enabling SQLCMD mode, execute the following:
SET NOEXEC OFF; 
*/
:setvar __IsSqlCmdEnabled "True"
GO
IF N'$(__IsSqlCmdEnabled)' NOT LIKE N'True'
    BEGIN
        PRINT N'SQLCMD mode must be enabled to successfully execute this script.';
        SET NOEXEC ON;
    END


GO
USE [$(DatabaseName)];


GO

IF (SELECT OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpErrors')) IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmpErrors
GO
CREATE TABLE #tmpErrors (Error int)
GO
SET XACT_ABORT ON
GO
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
GO
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
PRINT N'Dropping [dbo].[webpages_UsersInRoles]...';


GO
DROP TABLE [dbo].[webpages_UsersInRoles];


GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0
   AND @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;
    END

IF @@TRANCOUNT = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT  INTO #tmpErrors (Error)
        VALUES                 (1);
        BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    END


GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #tmpErrors) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
GO
IF @@TRANCOUNT>0 BEGIN
PRINT N'The transacted portion of the database update succeeded.'
COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
ELSE PRINT N'The transacted portion of the database update failed.'
GO
DROP TABLE #tmpErrors
GO
PRINT N'Update complete.';


GO

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

I haven't had much experience at all with Stored Procedures and any assistance or input is appreciated. Simply trying to make a repetitive task a bit easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE DropTables
AS
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE Table1
    DROP TABLE Table2
    DROP TABLE Table3
    DROP TABLE Table4
END
GO
```

Call it with `EXEC DropTables`